# Is it possible/how to create operator classes in GCP postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

Creation of operator classes in postgresql requires the superuser attribute on the role you're using - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-createopclass.html.

> The user who defines an operator class becomes its owner. Presently, the creating user must be a superuser. (This restriction is made because an erroneous operator class definition could confuse or even crash the server.)

However, GCP does not allow you to add the superuser attribute to a role - https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/users.

> The postgres user is part of the cloudsqlsuperuser role, and has the following attributes (privileges): CREATEROLE, CREATEDB, and LOGIN. It does not have the SUPERUSER or REPLICATION attributes.

Is there any way to create operator classes in GCP postgresql?  If so, then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in a limited way, by using [PostgreSQL Extensions](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/extensions) for Cloud SQL. Such as `btree_gin` or `btree_gist`. Unfortunately, if it is not on this [list](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/extensions#data-type) then it can't be done.

If you need to request a new extension, you can vote for it  by finding it on the [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) (look for `Cloud SQL`) or creating a new issue.